# Zend Server SSL Error

Tags: https, openssl, virtualhost, zend-server-ce

I'm having a weird issue with trying to setup SSL (https) on Zend Server CE for OSX.  Currently I am running Zend Server 5.5.

```
$ sudo zendctl.sh version
Password:
Zend Server version: 5.5.0
```

**I created a self-signed certificate in the correct directory using this**:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt \
> -days 365 -nodes
```

**I already uncommented this out in my httpd.conf**:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

**And I added this to my httpd-vhost.conf file**:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

**And these are my vhost conf for the site (I'm trying to use one directory for both SSL and port 80 requests)**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.local
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>

#this is the HTTPS version
<VirtualHost mydomain.local:443>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.local:443
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

**When I try to load the site in my browser (FF) using https://mydomain.local/ I get this**:

> The connection was interrupted
>   The connection to mydomain.local was interrupted while the page was loading.

**So I tried this with the openssl command**:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mydomain.local:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
20743:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.1/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:607:
```

---

*Additionally, I can get to the site by going to http://mydomain.local:443 but not https.*

### What does this error mean? Why can't I load my site with HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup SSL for your VHost on :443...

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/crt.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/key.key
```

Comment: Yep that did it! Epic fail. I didn't realize that had to go _right in_ the vhost conf for that domain. You're the man thanks!